# SES URL feature of Mach ii not working properly

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mach-ii

I have defined the following properties in mach-ii.xml file:

```
<property name="urlParseSES" value="true" />
<property name="urlDelimiters" value="/|/|/" />
<property name="urlBase" value="index.cfm" />
```

and in my index.cfm page there is a link

```
<a href=#BuildUrl("showUser", "id=#user_id#")#>View User</a>
```

in my listener I am getting the error the "Element ID is undefined in URL." Whereas I can see the parameter id and its value in the URL. Is anybody know why I am getting this error?
The other problem is, when I am clicking on the other links in the page, it is keep on appending the link in the URL instead of making the new URL.
First time when I am loading my site it loads css and js properly but after clicking on some link it breaks the css and js.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be referencing the id value in your listener as part of the current event structure (ie; `arguments.event.getArg("id")`), not the URL scope (ie; `URL.id`).

Your `urlBase` value should also be absolute from the webroot, so that if the app is at the base of your webroot, the urlBase value would be `/index.cfm` or if the app is inside a folder called myApp that it just off the webroot, the urlBase value would be `/myApp/index.cfm`